# Creating a Business Type Application Using Silverlight 3 - Is it Appropriate?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm considering using Silverlight for a business type application which will contain probably a dozen or so screens. The screens will contain data entry forms with edit fields, grids, lookups, calendars, etc. Typical business application type screens. I want this to run in the browser but don't want to mess with HTML, JavaScript, CSS etc. Is Silverlight 3 appropriate for this type of application? Can someone build professional level business type apps with Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Randy Minder,

Glad to hear that you want to use silverlight 3 for line of business application.

I used to develop line of business applications in ASP.NET combined with javascript/AJAX. I am currently developing my first silverlight 3 line of business application and found silverlight is better in few departments. The following are the Pro/Cons observed by me **PERSONALLY**.

Pros

1. **Layout/Styling(CSS)**
   XAML + silverlight 3 styling is very flexible and less cluttered when compared to CSS. I am not a designer and I hate having to deal with CSS. But in the case of silverlight, I really enjoyed creating the mockup,layout & styling. The end result is awesome. This is the first application that I developed has decent & consistent look & feel. I hope you will also find silverlight xaml to be easier to deal with.
2. **Rich Interaction & Language support**
   I used  to use Ajax, javascript for creating rich interaction experiences like populating some data dynamically when user interacts with UI. Writing some complex UI logic in Javascript is daunting. Though there are some nice javascript libraries like Jquery, I think writing UI complex logic in C#/VB.NET/F# is much easier than to write it in javascript. Dealing with rich interactive controls in silverlight is much easier than with javascript/ ajax controls. Writing server communication code with WCF or WCF RIA service is far easier than with ajax calls.
3. **Browser compatibility**
   Each browser is different from another in one or the other way, like some browser supports something and others dont. Having to deal with browser differences in javascript is also a pain. Silverlight being a plugin doesn't have to deal with browser differences. No problems dealing with layout engine differences too.
4. **Animations/multimedia**
   Ofcourse with line of business applications we will not use toooo much of animations/multimedia. However we can use small animations like menu popup, sliding controls, fading transitions for when data changes etc. These are very easy to implement in silverlight than with asp.net/javascript
5. **Validation** 
   Validation support in silverlight is awesome you can write more validation logic in less time.
6. **Popup messages**
   Popup messages are very clumsy to deal in ASP.NET and sometimes I need to store some information in hidden fields to feed text for popup messages. Hidden fields are used as javascript & ASP.NET interaction components which are difficult to maintain and end up with more code.
7. **Good separation of presentation & model** 
   Though you can separate these layers in ASP.NET also, silverlight enforces this by design which is good. In my team there are few developers who dont want to put effort on separation of the layers. Unfortunately they are the seniors in age and decision makers. I always hate to deal with their spaghetti code. Not to say that I am a better developer than them, I always put some effort to separate the concerns and try to learn how to manage my code. ASP.NET webforms doesnt enforce separation of presentation & model by design. Where as silverlight enforces this by design and my life became easier.

Cons

1. **Clipboard**
   Users are very much used to copy the content available on ASP.NET/HTML page. Most of the silverlight 3 controls doesnt support clipboard out of the box. The only control I know that supports out of the box is textbox.
2. **Database Communication** 
   Database communication in ASP.NET is easier & direct communication is possible. However silverlight being client side technology it doesnt have direct access to database and a necessity of creating an additional tier is mandatory. Though WCF RIA services make the development of this additional tier easier, still WCF RIA services is in beta as of now. Though I am mentioning it as disadvantage, I did not really feel it is as REAL disadvantage because creating a WCF service is not that difficult.
3. **Client side resource usage** 
   Though cost of hardware reduced alot,client side hardware resources are not unlimited when compared to server side. At my work place, though PC provided have decent configuration, most of the users open lot of applications simultaneously which is required to accomplish their day to day tasks. Silverlight uses client side CPU/memory. Some of my users are complaining that the application I developed is using more CPU/memory than the asp.net equivalent. So if your users have slower PCs, consider ASP.NET or design your silverlight application more carefully.

One may say installing silverlight plugin as disadvantage, I did not face the problem because my application is a intranet application and all users installed silverlight with a single email request.

These are MY experiences with silverlight 3. The only major issue I faced was clipboard support in silverlight, I hope MSFT will address this soon.

All in all, silverlight ROCKS!!! Silverlight 3 is ready for enterprise and if you can wait for few more months Silverlight 4 will be released which has even better support for line of business applications. I dont want to develop ASP.NET applications anymore, that doesnt mean that I will quit using ASP.NET, I will use it only when necessary. I fell in love with silverlight and for a good reason. Designing part of the website is the one I used to hate most but with silverlight designing became one of my favorites.

I hope that silverlight 3 will help you in your decision making.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Are you using any third party controls to supplement the controls that come with VS? I'm really going to need a full featured and powerful grid. Much like I'd have in a WinForm app using something like Telerik.

Comment: I did not use Telerik datagrid either in winforms or in silverlight. I dont know for which purpose you are using Telerik datagrid. Can you please let me know for which purpose you are using telerrik datagrid for?

My personal experience with silverlight is you can customize with almost everything, you can embedded almost all controls in datagrids like datagrid,listbox,radio buttons,  comboboxes etc, you can change styling completely. Please let me know your scenario.

Comment: My application is going to involve many screens where I need to display sometimes large lists of data, and allow the user to modify this data. I need a powerful, full-featured grid to make this happen. In a Winform app, this would be a non-issue. I just don't know if anyone makes a Grid control for Silverlight that would offer the same functionality as a Winform grid (like Telerik or Infragistics) offers.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Take a look at this post about the Vancouver Olympics:

http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/02/vancouver-olympics-howd-we-do-that.html

That's just one example of a business application in the "real world" being used to drive a massively complex operation. I posted that just to draw attention to the "business" side of Silverlight, but be sure to click the link to the original post to see the other partners and contributions to the project.

I've been building enterprise/business applications with Silverlight for over a year now. So the answer is an emphatic "Yes, you can" and "Yes, it's been done" and "Yes, it's been done on a large scale with large companies, and very successfully."

Answer (score 0):

I agree @Jeremy. Make sure to use RIA Services with Silverlight , You will get a very manageable/maintainable application. Even one more benefit is that you can make the SL app Out of browser too.